# SwiftUI bug? ScrollView , Data Sources, Did Load?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a for each loop which works for ONE data source but not the other. The data sources are identical. They contain the exact same data. This WORKS:

```
struct FirstCarousel: View {

 let firstDataCollection =  StartingCollection.startingCollectionData()
 let secondDataCollection = SecondCollection.secondCollectionData()

 var body: some View {
  VStack(alignment: .leading){
   Text("List")
    .font(.headline)

   ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
    HStack{
     ForEach( firstDataCollection, id: \.self) { collectTwo in
      TopCarouselCard(collection: collectTwo)
      .frame(maxWidth: 112,  alignment: .topLeading)
     }
    }
   })
  }
 }
}
```

But when I replace with:

```
ForEach( secondDataCollection, id: \.self) { collectTwo in...
```

It does NOT work.

The data collections:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct StartingCollection: Identifiable, Hashable{
    var id: Int
    let title: String
    let image: String

    static func startingCollectionData() -> [StartingCollection]{
        return [StartingCollection(id: 01, title:"One", image: "red"),
                StartingCollection(id: 02, title:"Two", image: "green"),
                StartingCollection(id: 03, title:"Three", image: "yellow"),
                StartingCollection(id: 04, title:"Four", image: "blue")
                ]
    }
}

struct SecondCollection: Identifiable, Hashable{
    var id: Int
    let title: String
    let image: String

    static func secondCollectionData() -> [SecondCollection]{
        return [SecondCollection(id: 01, title:"One", image: "red"),
                SecondCollection(id: 02, title:"Two", image: "green"),
                SecondCollection(id: 03, title:"Three", image: "yellow"),
                SecondCollection(id: 04, title:"Four", image: "blue")
                ]
    }
}
```

Now, one thing to note: the ForEach loop works in the sense that it iterates over the array correctly. If I replace the enclosure with:

```
HStack{
 ForEach( secondDataCollection, id: \.self) { collectTwo in
  Text("Hello")
 }
```

I get the correct number of "Hellos" based on the size of the data source. The following also works:

```
HStack{
 ForEach( secondDataCollection, id: \.self) { collectTwo in
  Text(collectTwo.title)
 }
```

This does NOT work:

```
ForEach( secondDataCollection, id: \.self) { collectTwo in
 TopCarouselCard(collection: collectTwo)
 .frame(maxWidth: 112,  alignment: .topLeading)
}
```

BUT, if I change the data source it DOES work.

As a side note, this view is embedded in a main view which includes another carousel that follows the same exact format. The other carousel works regardless of the data source.

```
struct LookView: View {
 var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
   ScrollView(.vertical, content: {
    VStack(spacing:0){
     FirstCarousel()
     FreeCarousel()
    }
   })
   .navigationBarTitle("Choose Your Theme")
  }
 }
}
```

The carousel views are identical. The other view also has the same issue when I change data sources.

Is this a compiler bug? Is there something I'm overlooking, or a need to load somehow?

UPDATE:
As noted in the comments, one thing missing was the TopCarouselCard View which is where the issue was. In this case:

```
struct ApplyScreen: View {
 var collection: StartingCollection
```

This is what caused the error because it was specifically expecting a collection that is a StartingCollection.

Comment: it seems `TopCarouselCard(collection: collectTwo)` has a problem. What type is the `collection`?

Comment: You got it right. TopCarouselCard was explicitly calling the first data type:  var collection:StartingCollection You pointed in exactly the right direction. If you'd like to respond I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments (which I will accept as right answer if posted in that way):

> TopCarouselCard was explicitly calling the first data type: var
>   collection:StartingCollection You pointed in exactly the right
>   direction. If you'd like to respond I can mark it as the answer.